# Injecting string HTML into head in NextJS not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

We have a NextJS page combined with a headless CMS.

Within this CMS I added an option for the admin to save arbitrary snippets to be injected either in the head or at the end of the body.

In nextJS I was trying to implement it in two ways:

1. I injected the HTML within a div with the "dangerouslySetInnerHTML":

```
{this.bodyScripts && (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `${this.bodyScripts}`}} />
)}
```

This works. However, I have two problems with that. The snippet is not really at the end right before the closing body tag and it is wrapped in an unnecessary div. Both problems are rather preferences than real problems.
This method can not be used in the page head since I do not have an HTML tag I could use to wrap it in.

2. I tried to inject the snippets in the `componentDidMount` function of my page component:

```
      public componentDidMount() {
        if (this.headerScripts) {
          const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
          head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `${headerScripts}`);
        }
        if (this.bodyScripts) {
          const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
          body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',`${this.bodyScripts}`);
        }
      }
```

The snippets get injected and it seems they are not HTML encoded or anything. But they do not get executed.

For reference, I tried to create a script element and injecting that:

```
const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
let myScript = document.createElement("script");
myScript.src = 'some URL to a script';
body.appendChild(myScript);
```

This worked. But it defeats the purpose of injecting arbitrary scripts, the admin should have the option to add whatever he wants. I am aware of the security risks but we decided to do that anyway :)

I also tried to use appendChild:

```
const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
let div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = `${this.bodyScripts}`;
body.appendChild(div);
```

This did not work either. I am completely baffled since I do not understand why creating a script tag and injecting it would work but injecting a string variable would not. I used plain javascript to do it and as far as I know, nothing gets sanitized...

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You might want to check out this module https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Systematically appending elements in `head` and `body` might be approached from [Next.js custom `_app` component](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app).

`_app` component receives `Component` and `pageProps` and could:

- use [`next/head`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head) to dynamically append elements to the `head` based on `pageProps`
- append anything after page component based on `pageProps`